# $\mathbb{R}P^{n-1}$ not a retract of $\mathbb{R}P^n$ via cup product

Tags: algebraic-topology, solution-verification, homology-cohomology, alternative-proof

I want to show that $\mathbb{R}P^{n-1}$ is not a retract of $\mathbb{R}P^n$ for $n \geq 2$ **using the cup product**.

**Proposed solution:**

Suppose on the contrary that that $\iota: \mathbb{R}P^{n-1} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}P^{n}$ is a retract for $n\geq2$. This implies the existence of a retraction
$$
r: \mathbb{R}P^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}P^{n-1}
$$
such that $r\iota = id_{\mathbb{R}P^{n-1}}$. Applying the mod 2 cohomology functor yields
$$
H^*(\iota;\mathbb{F}_2) \circ H^*(r;\mathbb{F}_2) = id_{\mathbb{F}_2}
$$
This implies that $r^* \triangleq H^*(r;\mathbb{F}_2)$  is a non trivial homomorphism. We have $H^*(\mathbb{R}P^{n-1};\mathbb{F}_2) \cong \mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x^n)$ and $H^*(\mathbb{R}P^{n};\mathbb{F}_2) \cong \mathbb{F}_2[y]/(y^{n+1})$ both generators are of degree $1$. Consider $r^*$ applied to $x^n$
$$
0 = r^*(x^n) = (r^*(x))^n = y^n \neq 0
$$
The above yields a contradiction.

I would like some input on if this is correct. Lastly is there some other way to show this result using the cup product more explicitly?

Comment: This seems correct. I think you should say a word about how you know that $r^*(x)$ has to be $y$. (Because it can't be $0$ and then there's literally no other degree one elements... maybe that's obvious.)

Comment: Remember that cohomology is a **contra**variant functor, so if $r\iota = \operatorname{id}$ then $\iota^* \circ r^* = \operatorname{id}^*$

Comment: Agree that this is correct (noting prior comment).  I had an idea that you could do this with integral homology but that necessitates looking at $n$ even and odd separately and only $n$ even gets you to a contradiction (an isomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}$ to itself factoring through $\mathbb{Z_2}$ since $H_{n-1}(P^{n-1})$ is $\mathbb{Z}$ when $n$ is even).  This intuitively makes some sense that you need some further structure to get the full conclusion.

Comment: @SammyBlack that was a silly mistake, thanks for pointing that out